# Clarification regards polynomials and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

From what I am understanding, is that third degree polynomials are not vector spaces because they are not closed under addition. Where we can have P(x)=X^3+x^2 and Q(x)=-x^3+x^2, and the addition would result in a second degree polynomial thus not closed. Which seems to be the most common answer on the internet, and specifically on this website.

But does this not also apply to second degree polynomials? We can have a J(x)= x^2+x and a G(x)= -x^2. Where the sum is also not a second degree polynomial. However, I believe textbook is telling me that second degree polynomials are vector spaces. Or is it simply that it set up the general method to prove or disprove whether a polynomial is vector space or not?
[Textbook example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IZnF.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJq3h.png)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The textbook lets $a_2=0$

Comment: Another reason polynomials of degree only $3$ can't be a vector space is that a vector space must have a $0$ vector (additive identity element); polynomials of degree up to $2$ (or $3$) are a vector space

Comment: I believe my problem regarding this proof is that it does not specify that (a2 is not equal to -b2), where the result would not be a second degree polynomial and thus not closed under addition

Comment: The textbook is telling you that the set of polynomials of the form $a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$, where $a_2$ could be $0$, comprises a vector space, but you are correct that the set of polynomials of that form where $a_2\ne0$ is not a vector space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that polynomials of degree only $3$ (or $2$) are not a vector space.  Another reason for that, besides the one you gave in the quesion, is that a vector space must have a $0$ vector (additive identity element), which for polynomials is the zero polynomial.

On the other hand, as your textbook correctly indicates, polynomials of degree **up to** $2$ (or $3$) -- i.e., including constant and linear polynomials -- comprise a vector space with their usual multiplication by constants and addition.